# Extract structured data from plain text

Tags: java, string, json, parsing, structured-data

On input I have a plain text (in my case typically it will be HTML) and a "grammar specification" (some way for extracting data from plain text to structured data), then on output I need to have some structured data (JSON is fine but maybe there exists something better?)

Are there any libraries for this task? What are good approaches to specify "grammar spec"?
What are the best approaches for solving such problem?

Comment: Since when is HTML the same as plain text?

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you do have a grammar specification or not already. If yes, which format?

Comment: @DaDaDom because it _is_ plain text... That it be structured is another story

Comment: your choice will depend on the type of structured data you require in the output! there are n number of libraries available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tools for grammar based transformations:

- TXL http://www.txl.ca/
- Stratego/XT http://strategoxt.org/
- ASF+SDF http://www.meta-environment.org/

Addition:

- FPP (http://jffp.sourceforge.net/) is a flat file parsing library in Java that can be useful
- If the input file is only HTML, jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) is a Java HTML parser
- So is http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ or http://mozillaparser.sourceforge.net/ or http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately no. Each has its own declarative language for defining transformation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for HTML parsing and and [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for Java-to-JSON.

Comment: I like jsoup. However it is not enough universal as I required but in my case it will be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

to parse HTML you will need a DOM parser which is a bit lenient depending on the quality of the html code to parse it using your grammar spec and then you will need to provide a type of data structure that you want and there are libraries to do that stuff for you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jilapi](https://github.com/BinitaBharati/jilapi)

This takes in unstructured plain text and gives out structured JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Well if the structure of the plain text files are well-formed, why not use the Java [DOM API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) (or JDOM) combined with a DOCTYPE to create a DOM Object?  From there, you could iterate through that Object and easily convert it to JSON, using something like the [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.